# Background Width + Footer is streching more than it should

Tags: html, css

I have this website: http://www.ryansammut.com/orijen/contact.html.

The footer is also being more lenghty than it should in Firefox, but it's ok in IE and Chrome.

When I zoom in a lot, and scroll to the right, the background also goes away.

Comment: The markup on this site is really poorly done, your lists are all over the place, you should consider re-writing the markup so that is a nice easy thing to work with. The problem is probably due to negative margins somewhere.

Comment: @jimplode I am using lists for the header, and the footer mainly, is that a bad choice?

Comment: the footer issue was solved, I gave a fixed width to the footerItems list. All that's left now is the 5px at the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: @Ryan, if I look at the site with my 1600px monitor, it does not stretch beyond 1280px, if I zoom in using Ctrl+, the left side becomes unaccessible.

Comment: @Yuri - Please re-check this and let me know, about the CTRL + Thing, it's because I am using left: 50% and margin-left: -640px; to center the divs

Comment: @Ryan it looks like the same problem is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site has some heavy design problems...

But if I were to ignore them and just tackle the problem at hand in the easiest and dirtiest manner possible, I would suggest to add this CSS to the bottom:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
}
```

Due to the fact that I can't spend all my time doing your work, most I can do is provide suggestions for the future :)

1. Decrease the overall width of your
   site to be around 984px to
   accommodate more screen sizes.
2. redesign the container boxes layout,
   draw them out on paper if you have
   to.
3. read about grow-to-fit,
   shrink-to-fit widths in CSS and how
   to trigger them
4. use relative positioning and avoid
   using left/right if your
   inexperienced.
5. Install firebug and experiment with
   CSS using it.

**edit:**

Make 3 div's one after the other, with width:auto (default) for each.

call them #header,#content,#footer

give each div a sub div, with a class .sub and give them the same background as it's parent.

make the .sub class have the required width (1280px) and keep it equal between the 3.

give the .sub class `margin:0 auto;`

so your site structure will look something like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

and your CSS something like this:

```
#header,
#content,
#footer {
    width:auto;/*not necessary as it's the default value anyway*/
    position:relative;/*not necessary but will help later on*/
}
#header .sub,
#content .sub,
#footer .sub {
    width:1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#header,
#header .sub {
    background:whatever1;
}
#content,
#content .sub {
    background:whatever2;
}
#footer,
#footer .sub {
    background:whatever3;
}
```

is this what you want?

Alternatively if you don't want to alter your sites html, you can try playing around with min-width.
where in IE6, width is almost the same as min-width.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky What would you suggest that is changed? To be honest this design is kind of screwed up because I was designing it at first not to be strechable, then I had to make it strechable. But I would gladly accept suggestions to improve my work.

Comment: btw, having it set to fixed width, will only make it worse, because then if I zoom out, or view it from a larger resolution the background would not stretch.

Comment: @Ryan by the looks of the site, it looks completely like a fixed width website. The easiest way for you is to sit down and redesign it again from zero to be strechable :) to do this you have to use `em` for all the widths, at least thats what I would do.

Comment: @Ryan hmm, so you want a fluid webpage... keep in mind, there are multiple ways to stretch webpages, it can be text based zoom or the new fullpage zoom. Also with your current solution it does not stretch to fullsize on my 1600px wide monitor anyway, would you like it to do that?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Only use lists when you have lists or list-type stuff, like navigation menus or search results. For stuff like the header and footer, use `div`s. Google is a good resource here - there are countless articles and tutorials on the subject of good web design :-)

Comment: I am using Div's not tables, how do you usually style navigation menus, without using lists?

Comment: @Ryan I think he didn't read the question. Anyway, could you explain a little more what you want the webpage (especially the banner and the top navigation) to do when you zoom in or out?

Comment: @Yuri, well basically I need that the backgrounds for the header, content and footer are repeated throughout the page. Therefore I couldn't use your code which says that the body is 1280px, What I did to solve this issue with having some pixels on the right was reduce the size to 1270px. I usually design at 960px but this design was given me by the designer, even tough I don't agree with it, I had to do it as it is.

Comment: I use relative positioning, but don't I still have to use left, top attributes for styling? Or do you use margins instead?

Comment: @Yuri - the main problem I have now is having extra space beneath the footer in firefox.

Comment: @Ryan yeah, use margins they go better with the flow, it's rare to actually need left/right, what your using left and right for is currently handled with floats. While the space beneath is caused by the image within #line1, not sure why yet.

Comment: @Ryan if you would explain how you want the webpage to strech, I could draw you a very simple page of how to align the page to do what you want.

Comment: @Yuri - Basically I have 3 main divs, header, content and footer all have their own background image. Is this what you need to know?

Comment: @Ryan no, I need to know how you plan to have the content stretch, if it's just the background thats stretching, while the content is fixed width, then say so.

Comment: @Yuri - Yes this is being done so the backround is streched, the content will remain as is.

Comment: @Yuri I think your concept is similar to mine, btw all the bugs are fixed in my website, just have 1 small one in the footer, in firefox it's having an extra 250px at the bottom, just in firefox.

Comment: @Ryan that 260px gap is caused by the img within #line1, not sure how to fix it, but removing it fixes the gap. Also I can still see plenty of problems: zooming in hides the sides, reducing the size of the window makes the left side become inaccessible in firefox.

Comment: @Yuri - The reason why the left becomes inaccessible is because for centering I am using left: 50%; margin-left: 640px; because margin-left: auto; did not work here.